# Windows 7 visual effects explanation

Tags: windows-7, visual-effects

I am trying to remove visual effects that are not necessary, 
so I am trying to understand what each effects does so I can decide if I should keep or remove it.

I haven't been able to find a reference on the internet and there is nothing in the help file to explain what each individual check box does.

Can someone explain the options and what they do?

I need an explanation of the following options:

- animations in the taskbar and start menu
- save taskbar thumbnail previews
- Animate controls and elements inside windows

[image: Visual Effects dialog]

Comment: Which ones do you know what they do?

Comment: well i mainly dont understand what these options do 
"animations in the taskbar and start menu"
"save taskbar  thumbnail previews"
"Animate controls and elements inside windows"

Comment: Try disabling then and see if you still like what happens to your start menu, task bar etc.

Comment: @DavidPostill i did that exactly with the rest options (and found out what they do) , but these 3 don't seems to do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What does "Animate controls and elements inside windows" do?

> Turn this off to nix the slow-fade effect on buttons and tabs in
> dialog boxes, the cyclic pulsating effect on the default button, and
> the fading scrollbar arrows. Buttons will still glow blue as you roll
> over them with the mouse, but they’ll do it sans the delay.

#### What does "Animate windows when minimizing and maximizing" do?

> This controls the squeezing and stretching that happens to windows
> when you minimize, restore, and maximize them. Leave it on to see
> where a window went when you minimize it, or turn it off to make
> windows pop into position when you minimize, maximize, and restore.
> This option also affects the disappearing/reappearing taskbar if you
> have both the Auto-hide the taskbar setting in Taskbar and Start Menu
> Properties and the Show window contents while dragging option
> (described later) enabled.

#### What are "Animations in the taskbar and Start Menu"?

> This controls the animated jump lists (see Chapter 2), fading task
> thumbnail previews, and the sliding taskbar buttons. Turn it off to
> speed up the taskbar. This setting was named Slide taskbar buttons in
> earlier versions of Windows.

Source [Windows 7 Annoyances: Tips, Secrets, and Solutions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596157622)

Comment: Wow there is a book that is just discussing the annoyances of win 7 ? :)